# Limit of increasing piecewise function is increasing?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose we have a sequence of functions defined on some interval $[0,1]$ which are piecewise constant and each of the functions is also increasing. It converges (when you shrink the partitions of $[0,1]$ so as to get a non-piecewise function) in some $L^p$ space to a function. Is the limit also increasing?

Do we not need some convergence in $C^0$ spaces to say this?

Comment: How can *one* element of a space (in your case a function) converge to another? That's like saying that $2$ converges to $1$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p(\lambda)$, then we get for some subsequence also that $f_{n_k} \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere. Let $N$ be the (measurable) nullset such that $f_{n_k}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x \notin N$ For any $x \le y$ with $x,y, \notin N$, we get that $$f(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{n_k}(x)  \le\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{n_k}(y)  = f(y).$$
Thus $f$ is monotone on $N^c$. Set now
$$\widetilde{f}(x) := \max_{y \le x, y \in N^c} f(x).$$
By definition $\widetilde{f}(x)$ is a monotone function with $\widetilde{f}(x) = f(x)$ for any $x \in N^c$. Any monotone function on $\mathbb{R}$ has at most countable (jump) discontinuities and is measurable. Thus in $L^p$ we have that $[\widetilde{f}] = [f]$, i.e. $f = \widetilde{f}$ almost everywhere. Of course, we cannot expect more in $L^p$.